# How do I get hubot to list all the users in the current campfire chatroom?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, bots, hubot, campfire

I've got hubot (https://github.com/github/hubot) running in a campfire chatroom.

I'm trying to make a script which shows all of the logged in users in the chatroom.

The default `hubot show users` command doesn't seem to find all of the logged in users.

non-working pseudocode

```
module.exports = (robot) ->    
  robot.respond /users$/i, (msg) ->
    for user in robot.room.users
        msg.respond user.name + "is logged in"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to send request via [Campfire room API](https://github.com/37signals/campfire-api/blob/master/sections/rooms.md), it will list all the users currently inside the room.